# Recursive function to select a hierarchy for a table without using connect by. PL SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I need to select all the tables that have references to my table in a recursive manner.

So, lets say I need to perform this task for the **book_author** table.
A query like this one:

```
select distinct sys_connect_by_path(a.table_name, '/'), level
  from user_constraints a
  join user_constraints b
    on a.table_name = b.table_name
 start with a.table_name = 'BOOK_AUTHOR'
connect by prior a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name
```

GIves me this result

```
/BOOK_AUTHOR/D_BOOK/JOBS/CITY/COUNTRY/REGIONS   6
/BOOK_AUTHOR/D_BOOK/JOBS/CITY/COUNTRY   5
/BOOK_AUTHOR/D_BOOK/JOBS/CITY   4
/BOOK_AUTHOR/D_BOOK/D_STYLE 3
/BOOK_AUTHOR/D_BOOK/JOBS    3
/BOOK_AUTHOR/D_AUTHOR   2
/BOOK_AUTHOR/D_BOOK 2
/BOOK_AUTHOR    1
```

, which is pretty much what i need.

Could you please help me to get the same result **without** using  connect by but with the help of the **recursive function** calls?

*P.S. Dont be confused with the mystical connection of tables books, jobs, countries, etc. - I've been playing with the foreign keys in those tables for quite a time - as I wanted to make my hierarchy really deeeeeep*

Comment: Just for curiosity - why should you risk overflowing stack and loosing heck of performance, when Oracle gives you such a fine instrument, as `connect by`???

Comment: By function I assume you mean PL/SQL and therefore don't want to use recursive sub-query factoring either?

Comment: I'm just trying to get to grips with some general concepts and one of the tasks I came across was to do the thing described without using connect_by. 2Ben It is a new thing to me to be honest, but I just googled it and I think that this recursive query factoring could do the trick as well

Comment: Please edit your question and include the layout of the USER_CONSTRAINTS table (column names and types, and an indication of what the primary key might be).  Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it [this USER_CONSTRAINTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_5249.htm#REFRN26047) @Bob?

Comment: @Ben - ah.  Wasn't thinking about the system view.  I really shouldn't be on StackOverflow until I've had my morning coffee...  :-)

Comment: You're the second person who's said something similar to me today @Bob :-). It's a little surprising as it's taken me 4 hours to be in a position where I think I might be able to stomach my morning coffee!

Comment: @Ben - sounds like the delayed side-effects of too much fun!  There's two possible cures: 1) take two very large glasses of water and in a while you'll feel better, or 2) take two very large glasses of beer and after a while you won't be feeling much of anything.  :-)

Comment: Guys, seriously? :) Could you please help me out with the problem so that I would be more eager to read about your fluid preferences

Comment: @Dennis, it is usual alcoholic weekend on SO.  :-)  Ask serious questions on Monday please.

Answer (score 1):

there is another way to perform recursive calls in oracle , using the WITH clase can do the work :
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_recursive_subquery_factoring_with_clause.htm